# Exercise 41: Learning To Speak Object Oriented

Tags: python

I am at exercise 41 and to be honest I am extremely confused. I don't know if it's because i've been looking at the damn thing for hours, if my brain is fried, or what?

I've gone over the below in prior chapters but for some reason this is not translating in english to me.

```
PHRASE_FIRST = False 
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True
```

What I think it's saying is that if "phrase_first" is false, read the list, if "phrase_first" is true then read the list in english? I don't know? I think it's the middle line that's really screwing me up here.

I need an english break down to get me back on track.

Comment: Might I suggest editing your title to include *what* Exercise 41 you're working on? Such as from what book/lesson? It might help future visitors find this page

Answer (score 4):

No, the code sets `PHRASE_FIRST` to `False`.

*Then* the [`sys.argv` list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is tested; if there are 2 values in that list, *and* the second value is equal to the string `"english"`, then `PHRASE_FIRST` is rebound to `True`.

`sys.argv` is the list of command-line arguments; `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script, and any extra elements in that list are strings passed in on the command line:

```
python script.py foo bar
```

becomes

```
['script.py', 'foo', 'bar']
```

in `sys.argv`. In this case, if you run the script with:

```
python script.py english
```

then `PHRASE_FIRST` is set to `True`, otherwise it remains `False`.

Comment: THANK YOU! Crying out loud, i've been looking at code for too long.

Comment: Dang you type fast :)    Out of curiosity, why did you say "rebound" and not just "set"?

Comment: @GreenAsJade: because that's what happens to names in Python. They are bound to a value (always an object). `False` is one object, `True` another. It also means the name is no longer bound to the previous value (which has implications for reference counting).

Comment: This website is seriously great.

Answer (score 3):

What it's doing is setting a variable `PHRASE_FIRST` to either `False`, or under a certain circumstance, `True`. The first part is straightforward:

```
PHRASE_FIRST = False
```

The second part resets `PHRASE_FIRST` to be True *if*:

```
len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english"
```

`sys.argv` is the command line arguments, starting with the name of the program, i.e. `exercise_41.py english` becomes `['exercise_41.py', 'english']`, **and** said second argument (`sys.argv[1])` has to be "english"

By not having the `len` check, the second part would error out of range. That's the only reason for the `len`. If those are both true,

```
    PHRASE_FIRST = True
```

All three lines could technically be rewritten more directly as:

```
PHRASE_FIRST = len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english"
```

But that's a bit harder to read for beginners

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to answer this. :)

Comment: I think it might be confusing terminology to say "you have to pass two arguments to the program".  In fact, you have to pass one.   The program name is the first element of sys.argv, but I would not have considered it to be an argument to the program.   "How many arguments does diff take?"

Comment: @user3183818 ... the accepted way of thanking for an effort to answer is to upvote.

Comment: ... and the accepted way to thank for the most helpful answer (that answered your question) is to accept it (the green tick).  I note that you have not accepted the answer to the previous quesiton that you asked...

Comment: @GreenAsJade, thanks for a good point. Edited to be more educational and explicit